# Raspberry Pi Ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

I've been using my raspberry pi through Ethernet connection normally. I am powering it through microUSB via my laptop's USB port. Everything was working normally until I installed a new version of gcc by following this guide. After successfully installing gcc I was using my pi normally until I lost connection with my pi.

I tried removing and re-plugging both the Ethernet and the microUSB connectors but nothing is working. When I power up the pi the ACT light flashes for a few seconds and then only the power led stays on. Usually when I plug my Ethernet cable all the other leds flash.

I plugged the SD card into my laptop and it works normally.

I connected my rpi to the monitor, I am getting the following:

```
[1.153151] ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown block (179, 2) 
[81.6939987]: random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

Any help?

Comment: We can only guess at why you installed a new version of gcc.  I don't see a link to the guide you followed.  The end result seems to be that you have left the system (on the SD card) in a broken state.  You could try the various troubleshooting guides but it sounds like you will have to reinstall the SD card from scratch.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely your problems are power related. A standard USB socket SHOULD deliver 100mA and up to 500mA if negotiated by the device (which the Pi can't do).

Neither is sufficient to reliably power the Pi. Try with a proper power supply.